# При отпускании одной клавиши срабатывают два обработчика

Tags: javascript

Доброго времени суток!

Есть код:

```js
    window.addEventListener('keyup', keyHandler);
    window.addEventListener('keydown', keyHandler);

    function keyHandler (e) {
        if (e.repeat) return;
        console.log(e.keyCode);
    }
```

Я зажимаю клавишу "вправо", потом "влево" - обработчики срабатывают нормально и поочередно в консоль выводятся коды этих клавиш. Затем если отпустить клавишу "вправо" в консоль выводится код этой клавиши и сразу выводится код клавиши "влево", хотя "влево" продолжает быть зажатой. Это происходит из-за особенностей свойства event.repeat. Что можно сделать, чтобы не происходило событие второй зажатой клавиши?

Answer (score 0):

Надо убрать `window.addEventListener('keyup', keyHandler);`.

Comment: Я вообще использую более сложный код в игре. И мне нужно обрабатывать событие отпускания клавиши. Только код ломается как раз из-за того, что после этого срабатывает событие нажатия второй клавиши, хотя я ее не отпускал.

Comment: попробуй удалить